# Recurrence of n-way merge sort

Tags: time-complexity, mergesort

For a regular 2-way merge sort, I know that the recurrence relation is

T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(n)

and for 3-way, it is

T(n) = 3T(n/3) + O(n)

so theoretically, if I decide to split the array into n bits (1 element by 1)

Would the recurrence relation be

T(n) = nT(n/n) + O(n)
meaning that the time complexity would be O(n^2)?

Comment: The recurrence relation should be `T(n) = w*T(n/w) + w*O(n)`, where `w` is the number of ways

Comment: @meowgoesthedog if the w is n, would that make T(n) = n*T(n/n) + n*O(n), which makes T(n) = n + n*O(n), which makes O(n^2)?

Comment: Exactly. The number of comparisons performed by the merge stage is bounded from above by `n`, not `n/w`.